# Laravel memcached errors after random time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, memcached

Hello I am using `memcached` in laravel application 5.8.

After some time the error is:

`production.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Code in controller is:

```
$page = \Request::get('page', '0');

           Cache::tags('posts')->remember('page-'.$page, 15, function(){
               return Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                               ->paginate(20);
           });

$posts = Cache::tags('posts')->get('page-'.$page);
```

The error comes, because of the `@foreach` loop in the view.

When I get the error, I can fix it by restarting the server, but this is not really a good solution. How can I prevent this issue and still use `memcached`?

I am sure that it comes from the cache, because if I change the cache driver to `array` than the error is gone.

**Update:**

So I have tried to change from `remember` to `rememberForever` in controller, but the problem remains. It errors and only solution is to turn off cache or reboot server. Otherwise it is giving me `production.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: Did you try to use `rememberForever` instead of `remember` to check if your problem is really related to elapsed time ?

Comment: No, this is a good suggestion. I will try it out and will tell if the error occurs again. Thank you.

Comment: @Marc The problem remains even after I changed from `remember` to `rememberForever` ill update the question so it is clear this can't help